# Qt doesn't create a component and doesn't return an error

Tags: javascript, qt, qt-quick

I am trying to dynamically create a element using QT, however it doesn't work and no error message is printed. Compoenent.Status is never ready. It doesn't even go to Compoenet.Error stage :(

```
Component.onCompleted: {
                var Component = Qt.createComponent("parts/Column.qml");
                console.log(Component.errorString());
```

The Column.qml basically contains a ColumnLayout element. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Isn't Component a reserved keyword?  Have you tried naming that variable something else?

Comment: @MrEricSir I realized that after writing the question, tried a different variable, still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating components dynamically in QML is a multistep process.  Calling Qt.createComponent() is only the first step.  The [documentation on this process](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html) goes into some detail.

In many simple cases, the component loads immediately and you can just do this:

```
// Create our Component
var myComponent = Qt.createComponent("foobar.qml");

// Instantiate the Component's object, give it a parent, and set its properties
var foobar = myComponent.createObject(parentObject, {"x": 0, "y": 0});
```

But in more complex cases, you have to attach to the component's statusChanged signal.  A complete example of this is in the documentation above, I've copied and pasted it here for reference:

```
var component;
var sprite;

function createSpriteObjects() {
    component = Qt.createComponent("Sprite.qml");
    if (component.status == Component.Ready)
        finishCreation();
    else
        component.statusChanged.connect(finishCreation);
}

function finishCreation() {
    if (component.status == Component.Ready) {
        sprite = component.createObject(appWindow, {"x": 100, "y": 100});
        if (sprite == null) {
            // Error Handling
            console.log("Error creating object");
        }
    } else if (component.status == Component.Error) {
        // Error Handling
        console.log("Error loading component:", component.errorString());
    }
}
```